# Regex , mathematical equation matching

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make mathematical equations validation using regex in Java. So far I have something like this:

```
(?:\\d+\\.)?\\d*([+\\-]?\\d+)?
```

It looks ok, but I still have some problems, with soliving situations like this:
"2"  - one single digit is not matched properly
3+5-sd  - when I have letters after some special sign it matches regex correctly
3-   - When I don't have second number regex is also matched properly.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you want to match - "equation" is very far from what your regex tries to match.

Comment: For example something like this:
(1.2*4)+2-(21.2+3)^2

Comment: @user3772508 That's not an equation; it's an expression. See Wikipedia: [Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation). Also regular expressions would not be a good solution for matching mathematical expressions--they are far too complicated for regex.

Comment: To add on to @p.s.w.g, you probably want to balance parentheses. That can be done in certain regexes, but itsn't part of the standard toolkit.

Comment: I know but I still would like to try it. If anyone could help help me?

Comment: And the solution without the parentheses like: 3*8^12-2/3 ?

Comment: To explain what @p.s.w.g hinted at: an expression is based on recursive syntax, and this can't be analyzed using regular expressions.

Comment: "...still like to try..." Your insistence is admirable, but it just can't be done. Real gurus have established the theory, and generations of programmers haven't disproved them.

Comment: It can be done, but with a regex that supports recursive syntax. What regex library do you want to use? (Perl, PCRE, .NET...) Java's standard regex lib doesn't support recursion.

Comment: First: OP never said anything about using just **one** regex – and with a few more regexes and a suitable function around it, yes it can be done. Second: I disagree, this one is not a duplicate, anyone who reads this question and the other must see that

Comment: Sigh. Regular expressions cannot be used to process context-free languages, only regular languages. Mathematical expressions are written in a context-free language. [Chomsky hierarchy 1956](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).